# How to load all records from kafka topic using spark in batch mode

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, kafka-consumer-api

I want to load all records from kafka topic using spark, but all examples which I have seen were using spark-streaming. How can can I load messages fwom kafka exactly once?

Comment: Can you add an example of this streaming behaviour and some pseudo code which show how you would've wanted to have it work? This show that you've put in the effort to find a solution yourself and deters people from thinking that you want people to write your code for you.

Comment: it is not neccessary, correct answer was received yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exact steps are listed [in the official documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#creating-a-kafka-source-for-batch-queries), for example:

```
val df = spark
  .read
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2")
  .option("subscribePattern", "topic.*")
  .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
  .option("endingOffsets", "latest")
  .load()
```

However "all records" is rather poorly defined if the source is continuous stream, as the result depends on the point in time, when query is executed.

Additionally you should keep in mind that parallelism is limited by the partitions of the Kafka topic, so you have to be careful not to overwhelm the cluster.

Comment: Note: the data returned here is just binary and still needs parsed